# Bash script doesn't executed properly inside docker container

Tags: shell, docker, gnu-parallel

I am trying to run bash script:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/fsl/5.0:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export SUBJECTS_DIR=/output
timefmt="%C --- CPU:\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys\t%P\tMem:\t%KkiBavg.,\t%MkiB max.\tExit:\t%x"
all_ids=()
for dirname in /input/*; do

id=${dirname#/input/}    # remove "/input/sub-"
id=${id%/}             # remove trailing "/"

printf 'Adding ID to recon-all processing list: %s\n' "${id}" >&2
if [ ! -e "/output/$id" ]; then
    # no output file corresponding to this ID found,
    # add it to he list       
    all_ids+=( "$id" )
    /usr/bin/time -f "$timefmt" \
    recon-all -s "${id}" -i /input/${id}/unprocessed/3T/T1w_MPR1/${id}_3T_T1w_MPR1.nii.gz -i /input/${id}/unprocessed/3T/T2w_SPC1/${id}_3T_T2w_SPC1.nii.gz
    printf 'Series with t1 found, subjects matched: %s ; %s ; %s\n' "${id}"
fi
done

printf 'Found ID: %s\n' "${all_ids[@]}" >&2

printf '%s\n' "${all_ids[@]}" | parallel --jobs 6 --timeout 300% --progress recon-all -s {.} -all -qcache
```

I made a docker container and it executed without any result, it just goes to the place and prints `printf 'Adding ID to recon-all processing list: %s\n' "${id}" >&2`, how ever if i run it with entrypoint=bash option with seperated command it executed properly.

Output of bash -x script.sh:

```
+ for dirname in '/input/*'
+ id=102311
+ id=102311
+ printf 'Adding ID to recon-all processing list: %s\n' 102311
Adding ID to recon-all processing list: 102311
+ '[' '!' -e /output/102311 ']'
+ all_ids+=("$id")
+ /usr/bin/time -f '%C --- CPU:\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%Ssys\t%P\tMem:\t%KkiB avg.,\t%MkiB max.\tExit:\t%x' recon-all -s 102311 -i /input/102311/unprocessed/3T/T1w_MPR1/102311_3T_T1w_MPR1.nii.gz -i /input/102311/unprocessed/3T/T2w_SPC1/102
311_3T_T2w_SPC1.nii.gz

+ printf '%s\n' 100408 100610 101006 101107 101309 101410 101915 102008 102109 102311
+ parallel --jobs 6 --timeout 300% --progress recon-all -s '{.}' -all -qcache
```

Comment: That's not a bash script. That's just a script, without a shebang, which means it will probably get executed by `sh`, unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: @muru i tried to delete shebang, but it terminates with an error: `Command terminated by signal 13`

Comment: You don't have a shebang, so how can you delete it?

Comment: I mean I tried it both with a shebang and without a shebang

Comment: Post output of `bash -x the_script.sh`.

Comment: @OleTange I ran bash -x entrypoint.sh inside a container and it works fine added output to question. But why it doesn't run with docker run sbi/container name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running shellcheck on your script and cleaning up the errors and warnings that come up? In my experience, doing  this does wonders for the robustness and portability of my scripts.

Shellcheck [has a website](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and is also available as an Open-Source (GPLv3) command-line tool.

Good luck!